# how to break down a list into multiple pandas dataframe

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge list with the length of 365.

Kindly help me on how to break each item in the list to a pandas dataframe, preferably by looping.

For example , I have a list d

d[1]

```
No Name 
1  xxx
2  yyy
3  zzz
```

d[2]

```
No Name
1  aaa
2  bbb
3  ccc
```

Likewise , there are 365 items in the list d.

How to breakdown each of them into dataframes

For example,

df1

```
No Name 
1  xxx
2  yyy
3  zzz
```

I am looking for a code which automates this process, preferably looping through individual items of the list and converting them as dataframes

Comment: Your sample data and your output ?

Comment: Hi Wen , I have updated my question. I hope it can help you to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your description

```
variables = locals()
for i,j in enumerate(d):
    variables["df{0}".format(i+1)] = j
df1
Out[856]: 
   No Name
0   1  xxx
1   2  yyy
2   3  zzz
df2
Out[857]: 
   No Name
0   1  aaa
1   2  bbb
2   3  ccc
```

Comment: Thanks wen 
Really appreciate your answer

Comment: Hi Wen , one question . How can I name the dataframe by ascending dates, like df(01-01-2017) and so on

Comment: @AhamedMoosa you can create a list of date , and using datelist[i] in loop